# Find Installation Date of Windows Updates

Tags: windows-server-2003, installation, windows-update

Is it possible to find the date when windows updates were installed on windows server 2003?

If I go to the controlpanel->install/uninstall programs and check the "Show Updates" checkbox it will show the windows updates that have been installed, but I don't see the installation date anywhere.

Comment: I just checked on a handful of our 2003 servers, and they all list the installation date for all installed updates. What mechanism are you using to install these updates?  WSUS? WU? SCCM?  Downloading the installers individually?

Comment: I was just using vanilla windows update with manual confirmation required to download/install.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try looking in c:\windows\WindowsUpdate.log

Answer (score 3):

You can also look here -  %windir%\SoftwareDistribution\ReportingEvents.log.

Answer (score 3):

In powershell you can do that : `Get-WmiObject -Class "win32_quickfixengineering"` easy and fast .

Answer (score 3):

From the command prompt, you can use the following wmic command to get a full list of the installed updates in html format:

```
wmic qfe list full /format:htable > hotfixes.html
```

If you prefer the csv format, use the /format:csv modifier instead:

```
wmic qfe list full /format:csv > hotfixes.csv
```

Answer (score 2):

I think Get-Hotfix has been available via PowerShell since version 3.

You can run it locally or against remote systems.

Locally:

```
# Get all hotfixes locallly

    Get-Hotfix

# Look for a specific hotfix

    Get-Hotfix -Id KB2693643
```

To get hotfixes for remote system(s), provide it -Computername with your list of systems.  (Note: This requires RPC open on the firewall between systems you're querying and wherever you're running Get-Hotfix from)

```
Get-Hotfix -Computername YourComputer

or

Get-Hotfix -Computername Computer1, Computer2, Computer3

Get-Hotfix -Computername (Get-Content \path\to\your_list.txt)
```

Answer (score 1):

Psinfo -h will show you the dates of install as well.  Psinfo is part of the [Pstools](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896649.aspx) goodies.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to the last successful update install time:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\Auto Update\Results\Install
REG_SZ: LastSuccessTime
```

This is a datetime value formatted as `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`.

Comment: Key doesn't exist in Windows 10 apparently.

Comment: apparently this applies not to all distribution, moreover this record is pretty unreliable as well.